# How to use "grep" command to list all the files executable by user in current directory?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, grep, command

my command was this

```
 ls -l|grep "\-[r,-][w,-]x*"|tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f9
```

but for the result I get all the files, not only the ones for which user has a right to execute ( the first x bit is set on).
I'm running linux ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK -- if you MUST use grep:

```
ls -l | grep '^[^d]..[sx]' | awk '{ print $9 }'
```

Comment: Thank you this is correct.Any idea what i did wrong?

Comment: Remove the asterisk after your `x`.

Comment: For clarification, `x*` means "ZERO or more occurrences of x".

Comment: Thanks man now it works and best of all I know why it didn't work. :D

Comment: One more thing, and I will edit the answer accordingly.  You should look for both `x` and `s` (SUID) in that field.
http://thegeekdiary.com/what-is-suid-sgid-and-sticky-bit/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` with the `-perm` option:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -perm -u+x
```

Comment: My question was how to do it using grep

Comment: https://edm00se.io/assets/images/post_images/right-tool-for-job-jekyll/scottySays.jpg

Comment: or `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable`

Comment: I was looking at that, Cyrus.  The question is, what does the O.P. mean by "user"?  If he means "user" in the sense of permissions (user, group, other), then `-executable` will not work.  If he means "user" in terms of "the current user," then `-executable` WILL work.  The `-executable` flag finds those that are executable by the current user, not necessarily executable by the owner.

Comment: @Jack: Yes, that should be considered.

Comment: i meant user in the sense of permissions

Answer (score 0):

Don't use grep.  If you want to know if a file is executable, use `test -x`.  To check all files in the current directory, use `find` or a for loop:

```
for f in *; do test -f "$f" -a -x "$f" && echo "$f"; done
```

or

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec test -x {} \; -print
```

Comment: Okay but I am trying to find error in my grep command , I was sure that I understand how grep is used and still can't find error here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk` with `match`

```
 ls -l|awk 'match($1,/^...x/) {print $9}'
```

- `match($1,/^...x/)`: match first field for the regular expression `^...x`, ie search for owner permission ending in `x`.

Comment: This will match directories as well.  Consider using `/^[^d]..x/` as the pattern